# file.js.php in cibonfire(codeigniter) Assets

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, javascript

Is It possible to include assets with `.js.php` extension?

I try this code, 
`Assets::add_js('file.js.php');`
but the file didn't included.

Thanks,

Comment: `.js.php` is not an extension. That is equivalent to `.php`

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at Bonfire's source leads me to [this line](https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/develop/bonfire/libraries/assets.php#L754), which could be the source of your problem.